# MySQL with promises - losing value

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise

In the code below, the goal is to populate the likes field for every post. I am querying the posts table and converting the posts to an object. Based on a value in this converted result set, I'm querying the likes table and am trying to add the corresponding likes result set to the posts object dynamically as shown below.

The likes field seems to be added successfully within the map function. However, due to some issue with handling the promises, the `likes` field does not exist outside the `then()` code block.

Any idea why this is? I appreciate any assistance on how to resolve this issue.

```
router.post('/load', (req, res) => {

    connection.then( (conn) => {
        return conn.query("SELECT userId, postId FROM posts");
    }).then( (postsRows) => {

        let posts = postsRows.map((r) => Object.assign({}, r));

        posts = posts.map( (post, i) => {
            if( posts[i].totalLikes ) {
                connection.then( (conn) => {
                    return conn.query("SELECT u.userId, u.first, u.last FROM likes l JOIN posts p ON p.postId = l.postId JOIN users u ON u.userId = l.userId WHERE p.postId = ?", [post.postId]);
                }).then( (likesRows) => {
                    posts[i].likes = likesRows.map((r) => Object.assign({}, r));
                });
            }
        });

        return posts;

    }).then( (posts) => {
         console.log(posts);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes:

1. Just chain the mapping together
2. No need to use `i` for access when mapping because the item is already given as first argument
3. Since you're mapping promises, you must use something like `Promise.all` to resolve them
4. You already resolve `connection.then`, no need to do it again. You can reuse `conn` from the upper scope.
5. Maybe you can also extract the object copying into a helper to clean things up further

Here's the code:

```
const copyObject = o => Object.assign({}, o));
connection.then(conn => 
  conn
    .query("SELECT userId, postId FROM posts")
    .then(postRows => Promise.all(
      postRows
        .map(copyObject)
        .map((post) => {
          const getLikes = post.totalLikes
            ? conn.query("SELECT u.userId, u.first, u.last FROM likes l JOIN posts p ON p.postId = l.postId JOIN users u ON u.userId = l.userId WHERE p.postId = ?", [post.postId])
            : Promise.resolve([]);
          return getLikes
            .then(likesRows => {
              post.likes = likesRows;
              return post;
            });
        })
    ))
)
.then(posts => {
  console.log(posts);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Doesn't Promise.all take an array of promises? also, can you please elaborate on this answer as `conn` is not set in the code snippet you're providing :/

Comment: @AnchovyLegend added a full example. And yes, `Promise.all` does take an array of promises. The reason you must do this in your code is that you have an array mapping that sometimes returns a promise, sometimes does not, so you can return `Promise.resolve()` in the cases where a post doesn't have a like to make sure the array only contains promises. Otherwise mixing async and non-async code can cause many problems, such as [Zalgo](http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony)

Comment: I appreciate all the info and the effort to put this response together, although likes still isn't being logged to console using the above example.

Comment: Well, I suggest you start debugging by putting a breakpoint on `post.likes = likesRows.map(copyObject)` and see if the query every succeeds.

Comment: The query succeeds as the likes field is set within the map function. but does not exists outside of it.

Comment: Everything succeeds up until the `likesRows =>...` code block. In there, post.likes are set successfully. However, when console.logging posts, post.likes isn't even in there...

Comment: Glad you got it working. If any of the adjustments are needed to my code, feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend thanks for the edit, I simplified your changes a bit

Comment: *Sigh*, and I thought promises were suppose to make these kinds of scenarios easier haha

Comment: @AnchovyLegend well they do, by a lot. For example, all you have to do is add a single `catch` at the end of all the promises and any error will propagate properly. Also, the code is more vertical without unnecessary callback nesting and handles execution order in a manner that is much more logical and easier to follow. Try implementing this with callbacks (including error handling) and then re-judge promises again :)

Answer (score 1):

Map doesn't change the value of the array it is called on. In returns a new array. I feel like you knew this already though and just forgot to add this.

```
posts = posts.map( (post, i) => {
            if( posts[i].totalLikes ) {
                connection.then( (conn) => {
                    return conn.query("SELECT u.userId, u.first, u.last FROM likes l JOIN posts p ON p.postId = l.postId JOIN users u ON u.userId = l.userId WHERE p.postId = ?", [post.postId]);
                }).then( (likesRows) => {
                    posts[i].likes = likesRows.map((r) => Object.assign({}, r));
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: The problem is also the nested promise.

Comment: @ThomasK, I appreciate the suggestion, however, this does not resolve the issue - currently getting a cannot set property likes of undefined error, also I suspect the nested promises need to be handled a bit differently.